# post using restler and node.js is not returning

Tags: node.js

I am trying to post using restler and return the response to client but response never returns .Below is code I am using and response is just hanging

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var rest = require('restler');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var port = 3001; // can also get it from process.env.PORT 

var router = express.Router();

//this is like interceptor for every route to validate all requests, logging for analytics
router.use(function (req, res, next) {    
    console.log('route intercepted');
    next(); // make sure we go to the next routes and don't stop here
});

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ message: "welcome to restful node proxy layer to business processes" });    
});

router.route('/someroute').post(function(req, res) {
    rest.postJson('http://localhost/api/sg', req.body).on('complete', function(data, response) {
            console.log(response);          
        }
    ).on('error', function(data, response) {
        console.log('error');
    });

});

app.use('/api', router); //all routes are prefixed with /api

app.listen(port);
console.log("server is running magic happens from here");
```

Comment: I am getting responsefrom upstream server without any issue

Comment: adding res.Send(data) fixed it